# Fedora 23 Apache and PHP not working

Tags: fedora, apache-httpd, php

I am struggling to get an answer to this.

I have Fedora 23 install, in place upgrade from Fedora 22.

When I go to http://localhost I get a list of files and folder and not the Fedora Test Page as it should be.

When I add a welcome PHP page that I got from another forum it just goes to a blank page, when I click on one of the folders which seem to point to a index.php it gives me code.

I have reinstalled Apache and PHP, removed and installed both but still nothing.

Any ideas on what is stopping it working?

Answer (score 1):

This post will answer your question. Basically apache does not know how to handle PHP files.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422140/apache-is-downloading-php-files-instead-of-displaying-them

> The correct AddType for php is application/x-httpd-php
>
> ```
> AddType  application/x-httpd-php         .php
> AddType  application/x-httpd-php-source  .phps
> ```